# Deployed flask server site - took too long to respond error

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to deploy a flask server in ubuntu 20.04 with nginx and I am following this tutorial:

my flask program is the test program in the tutorial:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='5000')
```

the config is the same as the program as well:

```
from islandbattles import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run()
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04#conclusion

Now, I am stuck at the end of step three, where when I try to run the app I get the following message:

```
 * Serving Flask app "islandbattles" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

So it's running fine, but when I try to access the site:
http://ip-address:5000
the page loads for about 1-2 minutes and then the response is:

This site can’t be reached ip-address took too long to respond.

The only difference in the tutorial is that I am creating the VM in GCP and not in digital ocean.

I have followed the tutorial closely, so the config is the same as theirs. Can anyone figure out the problem?

Comment: then you need to follow GCP tutorials, as each provider has its own kind of routing tricks

Comment: Look at this tutorial: https://www.cloudbooklet.com/how-to-install-flask-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-uwsgi-nginx-on-google-cloud/

Comment: It has the exact same start as the digital ocean tutorial

Comment: yes, but after they setup uwsgi + nginx proxy_pass

Comment: I didn't even reach that step, I just want the development server to work first.

Comment: yes, but you can't reach it from the outside until you set this up. if you want to test if your server serves requests on 5000 use curl, from the shell on the same VM and type `wget http://localhost:5000`

Comment: Ok. I just have one question: why in the tutorial they said that you can in fact reach the dev server?

Comment: the say that in the digital ocean tutorial, not in the GCP tutorial